# HTML5 Validation Pattern for example: 13-124132424

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I'm looking to validate that the user entered either `13-` or `14-` followed by a long sequence of numbers on a form field.

This one doesn't work: `(?:13|14)-[0-9]`
This one worked with just `13-` or `14-` but without numbers after: `(?:13|14)-`

Example of what valid data should look like: `13-9327493743409`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works great thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a quantifier at the end:

```
pattern="(?:13|14)-[0-9]+"
```

The `[0-9]+` pattern matches one or more digits. The HTML5 `pattern` regex is anchored by default, `^` and `$` are not necessary. If there can be 0+ digits after `13-` or `14-`, replace `+` with `*` (that matches zero or more occurrences of the quantified pattern).

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="(?:13|14)-[0-9]+" title=""/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: just wanted to mention that `[\d]+` would also match the same as `[0-9]+`

Comment: Yes, `"(?:13|14)-\d+"` is an absolute synonym of the `"(?:13|14)-[0-9]+"` expression in the current context. Actually, the non-capturing group can be replaced with a capturing one, it does not matter here much (I mean `?:` can be removed without any change in what the regex matches).

Comment: I think `[0-9]+` is much more obvious especially to people not familiar with regex so I didn't mean it as a correct